# Dart SqlJocky - No response from the database

Tags: mysql, server, dart, sqljocky

I am currently trying to setup a database connection between my server (command line server) and my localhost xampp mysql. this is running in my main function:

```
main() async {
  var pool = new ConnectionPool(
    host: 'localhost', port: 1234,
    user: 'root', password: 'password',
    db: 'angularsite', max: 5);

  var results = await pool.query("select * from discussions");

  results.forEach((row) {
    print('Row: ${row}');
  });
}
```

As you can see, it's basically the example that sqljocky provides. I just replaced the credentials with mine. I don't get an error message, nothing happens. From using the good old print method I know that the execution of the code doesn't go beyond the "pool.query" line. (The ConnectionPool does indeed instanciate)

Anything I did wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get when you add `print(results);` before `results.forEach(...)`?

Comment: Nothing. it just doesn't print.

Comment: I don't think it's related to your code. Sounds more like the database doesn't respond. Do you get anything different when you change the query to `pool.query("select * from discussions limit 10");` or `pool.query("select 'hello world'");`?

Comment: No, nothing at all. My mysql client is running, tho.

Comment: That's weird. Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: Yep, same :D Going to figure it out, I'll let you know if I do.

Comment: Oh wow, it was my dumb mistake. It wanted only the port of mysql, which is 3306 by default. Huh, in Laravel 1234 worked just fine for the database credentials... ^^

Comment: Weird that you didn't get an error.

Comment: Great to see you solved the issue. Just for SO hygiene, could you please put your answer-in-comment into a proper answer, and then mark this question answered? Also, it _is_ weird that the query didn't throw an error and hasn't timed out. Could you file an issue to sqljocky?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was that I was refering to the port of my localhost, and not to the port of MySql only. Entering 3306 as the port worked for me.